# How to go back in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to go back in Eclipse? Basically, when I'm jumping around a big project following the execution flow (ctrl + click and etc.), is there a way to retrace a step? If my code calls a method and I go to the method definition, is there a key combination that will take me back to the calling code?

Comment: For those who are searching for the same in Intellij, the shortcut is: `Control`+`Alt`+`Left (or right)` arrow.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> like you would in a web browser.

Comment: @FarmBoy have you tried Option-LeftArrow and Option-RightArrow?

Comment: @Jherico, I guess that swap spaces in his conf ( it does in mine ) http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#spaces

Comment: how do you map to a mouse click?

Comment: @Casey, not sure, never tried.  You might be better off asking this in a new question

Comment: It is not working for me on Windows. I tried changing the key binding from ctrl + Q to alt + left and restarted eclipse as well, but nothing.

Comment: Is there a place in preferences you can set this yourself? I spent years using cmd+[ on Mac and would like to now set that on my ubuntu machine (currently alt+arrow).

Comment: this moves to prev/next file, not to prev/next location in the same file (after clicking ctrl-<bean name> for example)

Comment: If given answer is not working, that means setting has been modified. You can reset to default and try. Windows -> Preferences -> Keys -> Restore Defaults -> Apply and close

Comment: @razor it does work in the same file, but you are right that it sometimes brings to the wrong place (not where you Ctrl-clicked from)... I can't explain why.

Answer (score 49):

On OS X:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> ( Command + [ ) : Go Back
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> ( Command + ] ) : Go Forward

Comment: I have Cmd+Alt and left/right arrow mapped to Spectacles, so this answer was quite useful.

Answer (score 23):

As Robin mentioned, you can also jump to the last edit location. Ctrl+Q is the keyboard shortcut for this!

Comment: `CRTL+Q` will take you to the last CHANGE location. Not to the last location you were. `ALT+Left Arrow` will take you to the last location ;)

Comment: Epic, I sadly used to 'Undo' then 'Redo' before learning this.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows/Ubuntu this was always

`ALT+LEFT ARROW = Go back`

`ALT+RIGHT ARROW = Go forward`

*However, on MAC OSX*, for me it was

`ALT(Option)+COMMAND+LEFT ARROW = Go back`

`ALT(Option)+COMMAND+RIGHT ARROW = Go forward`

Hopefully this will help other Mac people in the future who banged their head on the desk when the other answers did not work.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the keyboard shortcut mentioned by @lucas, there is the left and right arrow icons in the toolbar.  It also has a handy back to last edit location as well.

Both of these are of course reflected in the menu under Navigate as well.

Comment: The icon navigation does not work the same way. It goes to the last file, not the last reference location. For example, if your CTRL-Click jumped to a new location in the same file, only ALT-Left works.

Comment: no really... if i move in xml file (with beans definition) and ctrl-click on bean name, to jump to new place.  alt-left won't take me to the previous location (it'll move me to previous file - and it's something completly different)

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard bindings can change based on your OS and current Keys Scheme. So the best way to know a keyboard binding is to look up its Command in Preferences > Keys. That is also where you can change or add a keyboard binding.

Which means instead of asking for a shortcut, you should generally ask for the command (or at least ask for both). In this case the commands you want are `Backward History` and `Forward History`. You can see in the following screenshot that they are mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> in my Key Scheme (because I changed them to that).

[image]

As mentioned by others, `Last Edit Location` can be a really useful command also. In my case it's mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, but you check it under Keys :).

Answer (score 2):

These commands are very frequently used, so it is worth having all their shortcuts the same way in all your IDEs. To adjust them:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
3. Search for "Backward History" and "Forward History" and adjust the bindings.

For me personally Visual Studio's default Ctrl+- and Ctrl+= works best.

Answer (score 0):

For me in Eclipse by default it is done by pressing "Left-Alt + Left-Arrow" key combination.
You can also change the key combination of it in settings of eclipse which is exist with the shortcut name 'Backward-History'. I have made it "Right-Alt + Lest-Arrow" for my convenient.

I have also changed key combination for 'forward-History' as "Right-Alt + Right-Arrow".