# Eclipse inverse of F3 - Alt-Left doesn't always work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm loving Eclipse's feature of pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click) to jump to go to a declaration, but I also would like a keyboard shortcut to go back. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> doesn't always do that (it sometimes jumps to some other line in the class I'm visiting, but sometimes it does work, still haven't found a pattern in this) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> isn't useful as I didn't always have something edited.

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that in some cases eclipse put you via alt + left in a wrong place and there is no possibility to go back where you were. It's very annoying.

Comment: Finally somebody with the same problem :) Sometimes pressing twice works, but sometimes it's complete random where I end up.

Comment: This is infuriating!

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> seems to be the ultimate answer: [How to go back in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095318/how-to-go-back-in-eclipse)

This is also mentioned [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/navigation.htm).

Comment: the arrow is the left cursor key, not the delete button

Answer (score 3):

The issue is familiar and really annoying, sometimes it jumps back right and sometimes goes to other place.

The solution for this is:

Unbind the key that is called 'Back', because it confuses the editor with the `Backward History`

Window->Preferences->General->Keys
and search for Back

when you select Back clear its binding by pressing the backspace key in the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for reviving an old question, but since you still haven't got an accepted answer, I thought I'd give it a shot.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> seems to take you back and forth between visited files. If the declaration is in the same file I would expect it not to jump back, but I haven't got a working Eclipse installation at hand. I'm guessing that could be the reason you're not seeing it work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X:

Command + [ : Move backward in the editor navigation history

Command + ] : Move forward in the editor navigation history