# Open method declaration in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, methods, method-declaration

In Net beans, we can open the declaration of anything by pressing "Ctrl" and clicking on the target (whether it be a CSS file or method or anything else). How can we do the same in Eclipse ?

I saw several posts on internet that suggests pressing F3 on method name, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try ctrl+Click in eclipse?  it should work if you were to listen to [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706915/eclipse-inverse-of-f3-alt-left-doesnt-always-work) guys. So should f3. If they don't, try restarting eclipse.

Comment: I recently moved from Netbeans to Eclipse and obviously as my first mistake, I tried doing Ctrl+click but it didn't work. I have also restarted eclipse but no use. This is one of the reason I love Netbeans from the depths of my heart

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it manually, via the menu: **Navigate -> Open declaration**:

[image: Example]

Instead of you though, I'd try taking a short brief look to the [past:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769513/ctrlclick-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-juno)

-Ensure you set everything in the workspace right:

[image: like so]

-If that doesn't work, try to start over with the `-clean` parameter, as described [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html);

-And if everything fails you and you've come to the point where [nothing else matters,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI) you can reinstall it. Everything will be reset to default and it then, should, work.