# How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently, I switched from [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) to [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). Now I am missing the shortcut for navigating to the last cursor position in Eclipse. In Visual Studio, the same can be done with the help of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> shortcut.

How do I do this in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to go back in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095318/how-to-go-back-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Go to `Preferences / General / Keys`. You'll be able to see or edit the bindings for:

- `Backward History`: default is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>
- `Forward History`: default is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

You may also use those shortcuts (and see the key bindings) in the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: exactly what i am looking for , very useful short cut for coders

Comment: On OS X, it is  "cmd-alt Left/Right"

Comment: exactly what i am looking for , very useful short cut for coders

Comment: Wrong answer. Alt Left does not go to previous. In VB6 and visual studio, assume that you are working on Line 10 and then moving down and working on Line 20 and moving down working on line 30, now if you press CTRL + SHIFT + F2, it will go to line 20 and then again if you press the same key, it will move to line 10. So what is equivalent to this in eclipse ?

Comment: what a useful shorcut

Answer (score 14):

There is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> to navigate to previous/next cursor positions, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to go to the last edited position.

Answer (score 10):

I'm adding an answer, because I'm not allowed to comment yet. Though the dystroy's answer contains information about useful shortcuts, I'm not satisfied with it, because the mentioned Alt+left shortcut doesn't always navigate to the last cursor position (e.g. in the same file). I'm not sure how it works in Visual Studio, but in IntelliJ a similar shortcut always moved the cursor to the last cursor position, even in the same file. I would like to have such functionality also in Eclipse. For example: I move the cursor using the keyboard's down arrow key successively on lines 10, 20, 30. Now I am on line 30 and when I press Alt+left I would like the cursor to go to the line 20. After pressing Alt+left again I would like the cursor to go to line 10.

In Eclipse, when the cursor was in file A and I opened file B and moved the cursor down a few lines in file B, then Alt+left will move the cursor to the file A, instead of moving it to a previous cursor position in file B.

I created a separate question for this problem: 
[How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse if it is in the same file and was not edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483329/how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse-if-it-is-in-the-same-file)

Answer (score 6):

In Mac (OSX), the commands are ⌘[ and ⌘]. They are very convenient navigation commands when coding.