# Eclipse: navigate to method declaration in new editor?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way, when you navigate to method declaration with F3 or CTRL+LEFT_CLICK, to open that method declaration (when it is in the same file you are currently editing) in new editor tab? I'm working with huge classes and moving to different line in the same file just annoys me because I loose track of where were I in that file.
Also is there a way to navigate back to the previous place where your cursor was?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to navigate to the last cursor position in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313308/how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse)

Comment: @alain.janinm nope: that doesn't cover anything about navigating to a method declaration in a new editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 1st question, as far as i know, NO.

For the 2nd question, YES. See the below image, there are back and forward arrows for this.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Actually, your question is a duplicate question. Some googling would have helped you! Well I did it for you and found your exact(more or less) question with a chosen answer:

[How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313308/how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse)

Comment: Actually with the back and forward buttons, opening the same file in an other tab is quite useless. Also arrow doesn't go back to cursor position but to the line where you've jumped to the declaration. The arrow with * is the last place you've done an edit.

Comment: @alain.janinm Thank your for your remarks. You're right except that you cannot open the same file twice in eclipse as far as I know.

Comment: Yes you're right it has already been asked, I vote for closing this one. Thanks for adding the link!

Comment: @alain.janinm why vote to close? Please look again: you commented in the question that it's a duplicate, but the one you link to doesn't cover anything about navigating to a method declaration in a new editor, which is the main question here :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems not, but you can achieve the same effect with a couple of extra clicks, as follows.

1. From the Window menu, choose Editor, Clone. A new tab opens with the same code.
2. Navigate to the method in the new tab.