# How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse if it is in the same file and was not edited?

Tags: eclipse

I had used Eclipse earlier, afterwards I switched to IntelliJ for a while and now back to Eclipse. There is one thing from IntelliJ which I can't find in Eclipse: Navigating to the real last cursor position - even in the same file and even if the cursor was moved between the lines using the <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys on the keyboard or the mouse. IntelliJ is able to do it and I found it really useful.

For example:
I move the cursor using the keyboard's <kbd>down arrow</kbd> key successively on lines 10, 20, 30.
Now I am on line 30 and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> I would like the cursor to go to the line 20.
After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> again I would like the cursor to go to line 10.
After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> afterwards I would like the cursor to go to the line 20 again.

The following shortcuts are available in Eclipse:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> - it navigates back to the last cursor position in a different file, not to the last cursor position in the current file even if I already moved my cursor in the same file
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> - it navigates forward to the next cursor position in a different file, not to the next cursor position in the current file even if I already moved my cursor in the same file
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - moves the cursor to the last edit location

The latest version of Eclipse in which I tested the above-mentioned shortcuts: Eclipse Luna 4.4.0.

I found the following discussion about the same problem (lacking such functionality in Eclipse) which is quite old, but it seems that this functionality has not been implemented in Eclipse since that [discussion in eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/85990/).

Does anyone of you know if this functionality will be implemented in Eclipse? Is there a plugin for Eclipse which provides such functionality of navigating back to the last cursor position?

Please note, that due to the reasons described above, I'm not satisfied with the solutions provided as an answer to this [SO question 'How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313308/how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse) or to the other [SO question 'How to go back in Eclipse?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095318/how-to-go-back-in-eclipse).

Comment: You can use bookmarks to navigate by clicking, I think that is the only way today. Also, Ctrl+L to go to line or Ctrl+O to go to the Method.

Comment: I have not been able to find anything either, and it is anoying.  I have a file with 2000 lines of code (no, I did not write it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095318/how-to-go-back-in-eclipse)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Please read the question.

Comment: @studgeek: How to get rid of this box above my question "This question may already have an answer here: How to go back in Eclipse?". Did you add it? I actually explained already earlier in my question why the solution of a similar question ("How to navigate to the last cursor position in Eclipse?") to the question "How to go back in Eclipse?" didn't answer my question and why my question is different, but it seems that someone didn't understand it and marked my question as a duplicate of the question  "How to go back in Eclipse?".

Comment: It is upset. Still no solution from eclipse.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Preferences / General / Keys. You'll be able to see or edit the bindings for:

```
Backward History: default is Alt←
Forward History: default is Alt→
```

You may also use those shortcuts (and see the key bindings) in the toolbar:

answered Sep 7 '12 at 8:27
Denys Séguret

Comment: This is not the answer, please read the question before answer.

Comment: Maybe this is not the answer but it is exactly what I was looking for, that is to go back or forward where I was while debugging app.  Upped and thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use bookmarks for that because there is no another way of tracking the necessary code lines. Here is the link about how to use bookmarks http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2005/02/16/eclipse-tip-use-bookmarks-to-track-important-places-in-your-code/

Screenshot of the aforementioned article's content in the link:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is Alt+left arrow and Alt+right arrow to navigate to previous/next cursor positions, and CtrlQ to go to the last edited position

Comment: You received 3 upvotes, so I checked your answer using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0), because I thought that this functionality had been changed in a new version of Eclipse. However, it still does not work as described in my question (moving the cursor using only the keyboard's down arrow key or other keyboard's arrow keys). Please try to do the same steps as described in my question and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Eclipse's cursor history is rather unpredictable. The Alt+Left/Right shortcuts can rewind *some* cursor movements and navigation actions like others said, but definitely less precisely than many other IDEs. There is no alternative as of now.

Answer (score -1):

I use the side buttons of my mouse and it works for me

Comment: What kind of answer is that??? How this can solve the problem mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> brings you back to the last locations, where editing was done.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for an overview of shortcuts. See also [Eclipse shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html) or this [Eclipse cheat sheet](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_(3.0).pdf).

Answer (score -2):

> Navigate > Back (Alt+Left_Arrow) already allows to navigate back to previous cursor positions even in the same file. E.g. after you Ctrl+Click on a reference to a local variable (to go to the declaration), then Alt+Left puts the caret back to the reference.

[Exlpanation source](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241811)

Comment: The link to an "explanation source" provided by you doesn't explain anything. It's about an old bug from the year 2008. After seeing your answer, I had hoped that you meant a new version of Eclipse, but apparently not, because the bug is related to a very old version of Eclipse. Navigation after clicking something is a different case than described in the second paragraph of my question (moving the cursor **using only the keyboard's down arrow key or other keyboard's arrow keys**). Please try to do the same steps as described in my question and let me know what your result is.