# Go back to the previous place in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Two things

1. shortcut key to go back to the previous watched line of code in eclipse
2. Any plugin to see the references of a method just above the method?

Comment: Please define your question better. But I think you want to know a hotkey for 1 and want a plugin for 2, right?

Comment: I know about the go back shortcut, if you have a button on your mouse to go back, that should be it.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Q which goes back to the last edited line? Otherwise Alt+Left goes back to the previous cursor position in a different file. [Bookmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27129101/10226142) may also come in handy. Regarding references, latest Eclipse IDE releases provide code mining (_Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Code Minings_) which allows to show them above methods; does it suit your needs?

Comment: Also, I found ctrl+shift+L opens up all the shortcuts in a small popup. From that, we could choose the one we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> => opens all the shortcuts
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> => BACKWARD HISTORY
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> => FORWARD HISTORY

Answer (score 0):

- `Alt`+`Left` will take you to previous line
- `Ctrl`+`Q` will take you to last edit location
- To check the hierarchy of a particular method use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`H`. This will not show references just above but, hope this way you will get to know where it is being called from.
- `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` can be used to search a particular String in entire workspace, you can use the method name, this will search for that particular String in entire workspace.